# Is there a silicon equivalent to a carboxylic acid?

Tags: organosilicon-compounds

Can terminal Si on a siloxane chain have double bond O and OH?

Comment: Si generally doesn't support double bonds. At least severe steric effects would be needed to get such thing.

Comment: Is this good enough? http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/substance/silicicacid12345134398211?lang=en&region=US

Comment: That silicic acid is good.  And has that double bond: probably more acidic than a carboxylic acid.  I wonder if there is a sodium salt.  Thanks Zhe.

Comment: @WillK we can make salts, but in an ionic lattice probably $\ce{SiO3^{2-}}$ would polymerize to make tetrahedrally coordinated chains; the double bonds are split into single bonds by this polymerization. Some silicate minerals have this structure. If we take the ortho acid $\ce{H4SiO4}$ as the partent acid, then $\ce{SiO4^{4-}}$ remains monomeric and there are minerals with this too, but again there are no double bonds.

Answer (score 3):

Acids with a functional group $\ce{Si(O)OH}$ can indeed be formed. One such example is given by Xiong et al.[1](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201002970), illustrated in the abstract as compound 4 in the graphical picture below:

[image: Ligand exchange on nacnac coordinated silcon]

As can be seen in the illustration, the silanoic acid is not isostructural with a carboxylic acid. The silicon is tetracoordinate rather than tricoordinate, and although a pi bond is drawn the bond in the silicoxy group is probably more accurately described as $\ce{Si–O-}$. The negative formal charge is passed to the borane electrophile shown while the ligand $L$, a pyridine derivative, is hydrogen-bonded to the dissociable proton. The compensating positive charge is distributed in the nitrogen atoms of the ring. Compounds 2 and 3 show other possibilities involving a silicon-sulfur bond.

**Reference**

Xiong, Y., Yao, S. and Driess, M. (2010), Silicon Analogues of Carboxylic Acids: Synthesis of Isolable Silanoic Acids by Donor–Acceptor Stabilization. Angewandte Chemie International Edition, 49: 6642-6645. https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201002970